# Deprecation Warning: Using / for division outside of calc() is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0

Tags: html, css, sass

In these functions I compile `rem` to `px` and `em` to `px`:

```scss
$base: 16 !default;

@function scut-strip-unit ($num) {
  @return $num / ($num * 0 + 1);
}

@function rem ($pixels) {
  @return scut-strip-unit($pixels) / $base * 1rem;
}
@function em ($pixels, $context: $base) {
    @return #{$pixels/$context}em;
  }
```

But with Sass `v1.49`, we are facing this error:

```
Error
Deprecation Warning: Using / for division outside of calc() is deprecated and will be removed in 
Dart Sass 2.0.0.

Recommendation: math.div(scut-strip-unit($pixels), $base) or calc(scut-strip-unit($pixels) / $base)

More info and automated migrator: https://sass-lang.com/d/slash-div

  ╷
8 │   @return scut-strip-unit($pixels) / $base * 1rem;
  │           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵

Deprecation Warning: Using / for division outside of calc() is deprecated and will be removed in 
Dart Sass 2.0.0.

Recommendation: math.div($pixels, $context) or calc($pixels / $context)

More info and automated migrator: https://sass-lang.com/d/slash-div

   ╷
11 │     @return #{$pixels/$context}em;
   │               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Using `/` to make divisions outside of `calc` function won't be supported anymore. Here is an overview of the reason why form the [documentation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/breaking-changes/slash-div):

> Sass currently treats `/` as a division operation in some contexts and a separator in others. This makes it difficult for Sass users to tell what any given `/` will mean, and makes it hard to work with new CSS features that use `/` as a separator.

You should  either use `math.div` from `sass:math`, as an example  like so:

```scss
@use "sass:math";

body {
  font-size: math.div(50, 16) * 1px;
}
```

Or use `/` inside `calc`, as an example like so:

```scss
body {
  font-size: calc(50 / 16) * 1px;
}
```

Comment: Migration Documentation:
https://sass-lang.com/documentation/breaking-changes/slash-div
Automatic Migration
You can use the Sass migrator to automatically update your stylesheets to use math.div() and list.slash().

$ npm install -g sass-migrator
$ sass-migrator division **/*.scss

Comment: So what about the situation when using aspect-ratio in a SASS variable. This is also flagged on compilation but it shouldn't be as 3 / 2 for example is the correct syntax for aspect ratio.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid using sass:math, you may just use

```
calc(scut-strip-unit($pixels) / $base)
```

Comment: you should **not** avoid it, as the generated CSS will needlessly get inflated using redundant `calc` functions (also not performant)